# Material Getting weird artefacts as it moves away from Grid

Tags: materials

The Eye Material on my Character starts to have weird artifacts as it moves away from the Grid. It works as intended at the center. Since I use large sets for Animating the Shots, the character will naturally move away from the Center for certain shots.
This primarily seems like a problem in Cycles but in some characters it also happens on Eevee.

In the images below you can see that it works as intended at 0 but as I move it to a value of 600 on all axes it breaks.

I will include the Blend file for your reference. Please Note that the File uses Blenrig and was created using Blender v2.91.

Any Help would be greatly Appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like z-fighting. This happens when two surfaces (one behind the other) too close to each other and from a distance the engine can't tell which one is closer.

Comment: Any way to fix that ???

Comment: Try to create the eye from one sphere, not two concentric.

Comment: Not Working. I checked that the Scale of the eyes is around 0.05. The issue dissappears as I scale it up to 1. Would that be the problem ?? I cant unfortunately scale it upto 1 as my character would be huge then